# Use wordlayout results for ggplot geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, word-cloud

The R package wordcloud has a very useful function which is called wordlayout. It takes initial positions of words and their respective sizes an rearranges them in a way that they do not overlap. I would like to use the results of this functions to do a geom_text plot in ggplot.
I came up with the following example but soon realized that there seems to be a big difference betweetn cex (wordlayout) and size (geom_plot) since words in graphics package appear way larger.
here is my sample code. Plot 1 is the original wordcloud plot which has no overlaps:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)

samplesize=100
textdf <- data.frame(label=sample(stopwords("en"),samplesize,replace=TRUE),x=sample(c(1:1000),samplesize,replace=TRUE),y=sample(c(1:1000),samplesize,replace=TRUE),size=sample(c(1:5),samplesize,replace=TRUE))

#plot1
plot.new()
pdf(file="plot1.pdf")
textplot(textdf$x,textdf$y,textdf$label,textdf$size)
dev.off()
#plot2
ggplot(textdf,aes(x,y))+geom_text(aes(label = label, size = size))
ggsave("plot2.pdf")
#plot3
new_pos <- wordlayout(x=textdf$x,y=textdf$y,words=textdf$label,cex=textdf$size)
textdf$x <- new_pos[,1]
textdf$y <- new_pos[,2]
ggplot(textdf,aes(x,y))+geom_text(aes(label = label, size = size))
ggsave("plot3.pdf")
#plot4
textdf$x <- new_pos[,1]+0.5*new_pos[,3]#this is the way the wordcloud package rearranges the positions. I took this out of the textplot function
textdf$y <- new_pos[,2]+0.5*new_pos[,4]
ggplot(textdf,aes(x,y))+geom_text(aes(label = label, size = size))
ggsave("plot4.pdf")
```

is there a way to overcome this cex/size difference and reuse wordlayout for ggplots?

Answer (score 4):

`cex` stands for character expansion and is the factor by which text is magnified relative the default, specified by `cin` - set on my installation to 0.15 in by 0.2 in: see `?par` for more details.

[@hadley explains](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2-dev/N7oaqvjiKzg) that ggplot2 `size`s are measured in mm. Therefore `cex=1` would correspond to `size=3.81` or `size=5.08` depending on if it is being scaled by the width or height. Of course, font selection may cause differences.

In addition, to use absolute sizes, you need to have the size specification outside the `aes` otherwise it considers it a variable to map to and choose the scale itself, eg:

```
ggplot(textdf,aes(x,y))+geom_text(aes(label = label),size = textdf$size*3.81)
```

Comment: thank you. I just made the changes you suggest (I've got the same par()$cin defaults as you). Now the words seem to be of the same size but the words in my ggplot are totally overlaped. There words are fewer words visible textplot. see [plot1](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/stephan.schloegl/stuff/plot1.pdf)  [plot3](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/stephan.schloegl/stuff/plot3.pdf) [plot4](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/stephan.schloegl/stuff/plot4.pdf)

Comment: Actually it looks like it might be that textplot uses the position of the centre, while ggplot might use the position of the left edge of the text?

Comment: i suppose I should edit lines 23 to 24 in the wordlayout function according to the information you gave me in your first comment. On these lines width and height of each word are calculated based on cex value using strwidth and strheight.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly I think you're going to find the short answer is no! I think the package handles the text vector mapping differently from ggplot2, so you can tinker with size and font face/family, etc. but will struggle to replicate exactly what the package is doing.

I tried a few things:

1) Try to plot the grobs from textdata using annotation_custom

```
require(plyr)  
require(grid)

# FIRST TRY PLOT INDIVIDUAL TEXT GROBS
qplot(0:1000,0:1000,geom="blank") +
  alply(textdf,1,function(x){
  annotation_custom(textGrob(label=x$label,0,0,c("center","center"),gp=gpar(cex=x$size)),x$x,x$x,x$y,x$y)  
})
```

[image]

2) Run the wordlayout() function which should readjust the text, but difficult to see for what font (similarly doesn't work)

```
# THEN USE wordcloud() TO GET CO-ORDS
plot.new()
wordlayout(textdf$x,textdf$y,words=textdf$label,cex=textdf$size,xlim=c(min(textdf$x),max(textdf$x)),ylim=c(min(textdf$y),max(textdf$y)))
plotdata<-cbind(data.frame(rownames(w)),w)
colnames(plotdata)=c("word","x","y","w","h")

# PLOT WORDCLOUD DATA
qplot(0:1000,0:1000,geom="blank") +
  alply(plotdata,1,function(x){
    annotation_custom(textGrob(label=x$word,0,0,c("center","center"),gp=gpar(cex=x$h*40)),x$x,x$x,x$y,x$y)  
  })
```

[image]

Here's a cheat if you just want to overplot other ggplot functions on top of it (although the co-ords don't seem to match up exactly between the data and the plot). It basically images the wordcloud, removes the margins, and under-plots it at the same scale:

```
# make a png file of just the panel
plot.new()
png(filename="bgplot.png")
par(mar=c(0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01))
textplot(textdf$x,textdf$y,textdf$label,textdf$size,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",asp=1)
dev.off()

# library to get PNG file
require(png)  

# then plot it behind the panel
qplot(0:1000,0:1000,geom="blank") + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(readPNG("bgplot.png"),0,0,1,1,just=c("left","bottom")),0,1000,0,1000) +
  coord_fixed(1,c(0,1000),c(0,1000))
```

[image]